# If $\int_\mathbb{R} f(x)dx = \int_\mathbb{R} g(x)dx$, then is $\int_\mathbb{R} k(x) f(x)dx = \int_\mathbb{R} k(x)g(x)dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

Assume $f,g,k$ are smooth functions that are defined in all $\mathbb{R}$ so that $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f <\infty$(and also for g,k).

If $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f = \int_{\mathbb{R}} g $ , is it true that $\int_{\mathbb{R}} kf=\int_{\mathbb{R}} kg$ ? 
If not, that what are the conditions on $k$ that can guarantee such an equality?
(except for being constant of course)

Thanks !

Comment: Nope, it's wrong. Consider $k=f-g\ne 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not generally true. For a counterexample, consider $f$ and $g$ to be shifted smooth bump functions at different locations. That is, suppose $f$ is a bump function centered at $-2$ with support in $[-3, -1]$, and suppose $g$ is a bump function centered at $2$ with support in $[1,3]$.

We may suppose without loss of generality that $\int_\mathbb{R} f = \int_\mathbb{R} g = 1$. But choosing $k = f$, we have that
$ \int_\mathbb{R} f^2 > 0$ and $\int_\mathbb{R} fg = 0$ (since the supports of $f$ and $g$ are disjoint).

I note that one does not require bump functions for this example --- it just gives a very easy to state counterexample. Shifted Gaussians would also work, for instance.

There are no obvious restrictions we can impose on $k$ to guarantee the equality $\int_\mathbb{R} fk = \int_\mathbb{R} gk$, except of course that $k$ being constant suffices.